# Output specific JSON when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have some JSON I'm using to experiment with Euclidean Similarity as a baby-step towards Machine Learning. I have some buttons I created with HTML and CSS but I need a way to attach certain parts of my JSON to each button. You can see my rather pitiful attempt at this in the `similarity` function. In case I wasn't specific enough let me get into the details; for the movie *Dunkirk*, for example, I want the object for *Dunkirk* to be displayed when that button is clicked. For *Concussion* I want the object for *Concussion* to be displayed... etc.

```
<div id="dunk" class="movie">
        <div class="text">Dunkirk</div>
    </div>
    <div id="conc" class="movie">
        <div class="text">Concussion</div>
    </div>
    <div id="indep" class="movie">
        <div class="text">Independence</div>
    </div>
    <div id="freesolo" class="movie">
        <div class="text">Free Solo</div>
    </div>
    <div id="submit">
        <div id="text">Submit</div>
    </div>
```

```
.movie {
    height:50px;
    width:80px;
    background-color:grey;
}

.movie:hover {
    background-color:lightgrey;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#submit {
    height:50px;
    width:80px;
    background-color:black;
}

#submit:hover {
    background-color:darkgrey;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```
let data = 
    [
        [{
            "name": "Dunkirk",
            "action": 7,
            "suspense": 9,
            "drama": 5,
            "character": 2,
            "romance": null,
            "comedy": null,
            "sci-fi": null,
            "interestFactor": 7
        }],
        [{
            "name": "Concussion",
            "action": null,
            "suspense": 7,
            "drama": 8,
            "character": 9,
            "romance": 3,
            "comedy": null,
            "sci-fi": null,
            "interestFactor": 10
            }],
        [{
            "name": "Independence Day: Resurgence",
            "action": 9,
            "suspense": 6,
            "drama": 3,
            "character": 6,
            "romance": 2,
            "comedy": null,
            "sci-fi": 9,
            "interestFactor": 5
            }],
        [{
            "name": "Free Solo",
            "action": 3,
            "suspense": 10,
            "drama": 10,
            "character": 8,
            "romance": null,
            "comedy": null,
            "sci-fi": null,
            "interestFactor": 10
        }]

    ];

let jString = JSON.stringify(data);
let parseData = JSON.parse(jString);
console.log(parseData[0][0]);

let options = document.querySelectorAll(".movie");
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener('click', similarity);

function similarity(){
    options.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
            console.log(parseData[el][el].name);
        });
    });
    console.log("it worked");
};
```

Comment: Why objects are nested in two arrays? i:e outer array and then array for each individual object.

Comment: I dont see buttons where are buttons ? I see divs rather

Comment: @randomSoul So I can easily index through the JSON, I could've spent more time thinking about the formatting but I haven't much experience with JSON.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh The Divs have event listeners attached to them check out the `similarity` function, you'll see - sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: The click events are only assigned to the divs when you click submit. Attach those events immediately, and get rid of the submit button altogether and you'll be a lot closer to a working solution.

Comment: `parseData[el][el].name` should be `parseData[el][0].name` given your current structure.

Comment: @MikhailYourchenko - There is no need for enclosing objects in separate array. Array is used for more than one items and your `data` is array of movies, where each `object` is a single movie details. So, no need to enclose again that in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching `click` listeners to the `div` after you `click` on `submit`. Instead attach the listener on 
`divs`.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "name": "Dunkirk",
        "action": 7,
        "suspense": 9,
        "drama": 5,
        "character": 2,
        "romance": null,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": null,
        "interestFactor": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "Concussion",
        "action": null,
        "suspense": 7,
        "drama": 8,
        "character": 9,
        "romance": 3,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": null,
        "interestFactor": 10
        },
    {
        "name": "Independence Day: Resurgence",
        "action": 9,
        "suspense": 6,
        "drama": 3,
        "character": 6,
        "romance": 2,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": 9,
        "interestFactor": 5
        },
    {
        "name": "Free Solo",
        "action": 3,
        "suspense": 10,
        "drama": 10,
        "character": 8,
        "romance": null,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": null,
        "interestFactor": 10
    }
];

const movies = document.querySelectorAll('.movie');

movies.forEach((movie) => {
    movie.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const movieName = this.children[0].textContent;
        const found  = data.find(({name}) => name.toLowerCase() === movieName.toLowerCase());
        if(found) {console.log(found);}
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="dunk" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Dunkirk</div>
</div>
<div id="conc" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Concussion</div>
</div>
<div id="indep" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Independence</div>
</div>
<div id="freesolo" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Free Solo</div>
</div>
<div id="submit">
    <div id="text">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `includes` because the `text` in div is not exactly similar to the movie name. Example - `Independence Day: Resurgence`.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "name": "Dunkirk",
        "action": 7,
        "suspense": 9,
        "drama": 5,
        "character": 2,
        "romance": null,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": null,
        "interestFactor": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "Concussion",
        "action": null,
        "suspense": 7,
        "drama": 8,
        "character": 9,
        "romance": 3,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": null,
        "interestFactor": 10
        },
    {
        "name": "Independence Day: Resurgence",
        "action": 9,
        "suspense": 6,
        "drama": 3,
        "character": 6,
        "romance": 2,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": 9,
        "interestFactor": 5
        },
    {
        "name": "Free Solo",
        "action": 3,
        "suspense": 10,
        "drama": 10,
        "character": 8,
        "romance": null,
        "comedy": null,
        "sci-fi": null,
        "interestFactor": 10
    }
];

const movies = document.querySelectorAll('.movie');

movies.forEach((movie) => {
    movie.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const movieName = this.children[0].textContent;
        const found  = data.filter(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(movieName.toLowerCase()));
        if(found.length > 0) {console.log(found[0]);}
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="dunk" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Dunkirk</div>
</div>
<div id="conc" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Concussion</div>
</div>
<div id="indep" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Independence</div>
</div>
<div id="freesolo" class="movie">
    <div class="text">Free Solo</div>
</div>
<div id="submit">
    <div id="text">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go about this slightly different and give you some functions you can use to look up stuff in your array of objects (I removed the array in array, made a simple array of objects). the `lookup` returns an array (of one) and the `lookupAll` returns all matches in an array.  This will allow you for example to lookup where "suspense" is 6 etc.
Note I use the `data-name` to easily match by the name, you could do that for any or all the properties.

This also will work in pretty much any browser including super old like IE6.

```js
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.funcs = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
  movieFunc: function(ev) {
    let d = this.dataset.name;
    // console.log(d);
    let found = myApp.funcs.lookup(myApp.data, d, "name", true);
    results.textContent = found != undefined ? JSON.stringify(found[0]) : "Not Found";
  }
};
myApp.data = [{
    "name": "Dunkirk",
    "action": 7,
    "suspense": 9,
    "drama": 5,
    "character": 2,
    "romance": null,
    "comedy": null,
    "sci-fi": null,
    "interestFactor": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Concussion",
    "action": null,
    "suspense": 7,
    "drama": 8,
    "character": 9,
    "romance": 3,
    "comedy": null,
    "sci-fi": null,
    "interestFactor": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Independence Day: Resurgence",
    "action": 9,
    "suspense": 6,
    "drama": 3,
    "character": 6,
    "romance": 2,
    "comedy": null,
    "sci-fi": 9,
    "interestFactor": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Free Solo",
    "action": 3,
    "suspense": 10,
    "drama": 10,
    "character": 8,
    "romance": null,
    "comedy": null,
    "sci-fi": null,
    "interestFactor": 10
  }
];


let movies = document.querySelectorAll(".movie");
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
let results = document.getElementById("results");
submit.addEventListener('click', similarity);

function movieFunc(ev) {
  let d = this.dataset.name;
  // console.log(d);
  let found = myApp.funcs.lookup(myApp.data, d, "name", true);
  results.textContent = found != undefined ? JSON.stringify(found[0]) : "Not Found";
}
movies.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', myApp.funcs.movieFunc);
});

function similarity() {
  console.log("it worked");
};
```

```css
.movie {
  height: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.movie:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#results {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}

#submit {
  height: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

#submit:hover {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="dunk" class="movie" data-name="Dunkirk">
  <div class="text">Dunkirk</div>
</div>
<div id="conc" class="movie" data-name="Concussion">
  <div class="text">Concussion</div>
</div>
<div id="indep" class="movie" data-name="Independence Day: Resurgence">
  <div class="text">Independence</div>
</div>
<div id="freesolo" class="movie" data-name="Free Solo">
  <div class="text">Free Solo</div>
</div>
<div id="submit">
  <div id="text">Submit</div>
</div>
<div id="results">&nbsp</div>
```